# How can I Filtering API data(response) in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I am working on Reactjs application, I am doing get request to render the list item with **`axios`**, data is in form of json

in response, there is array which has type **`purchase`**, **`refund`** and **`Adjustment`**, i have to make a functionality by which i can filter array with **`types(onClick)`**, i have renderd list item but not able to filter according to the **`type`** given by API response, can anyone help me to sort out this issue,

**`this.renderTransactionSummary(txn, data)`** is a different function which is maping data from API to render list item

---

**JSON RESPONSE**

```
 "transactions": [
            {
                "amounts": 12.96,
                "balance": 0,
                "description": "",
                "occurred_at": "2017-09-23T19:18:21+00:00",
                "type": "refund"
            },
            {
                "amounts": 12.96,
                "balance": 0,
                "description": "",
                "occurred_at": "2017-09-23T19:18:21+00:00",
                "type": "adjustment"
            },
            {
                "amounts": 12.96,
                "balance": 0,
                "description": "",
                "occurred_at": "2017-09-23T19:18:21+00:00",
                "type": "purchase"
            },
  ]
```

**reactjs code**

```
render() {
    return (<Layout t={t}>
        <div className="content">
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="filterWrapper">
                    <ul className="filters">
                        <li className="active"><span>{t('wallet.all')}</span></li>
                        <li><span>{t('wallet.purchase')}</span></li>
                        <li><span>{t('wallet.adjustment')}</span></li>
                        <li><span>{t('wallet.refund')}</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="summaryContainer">
                    {this.renderTxnHeader()}

                    <ul className="summaryList">
                        {/* List Items */}
                        {transaction.map((txn, key) => (
                            <li key={key} className="txnList">
                                <div className="summaryBlock">
                                    {this.renderTransactionSummary(txn, data)}
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
            </Layout>);
}
```

**Image will make you clear**

[image]

Comment: So when you click a type you want to filter the data you have in memory clientside

Comment: yes @Zinc, this json data is coming from API and i want to filter the list item according to types(refund, adjustment and purchase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) [groupby](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) to group the data for your application and then send data to your application. The code should be :

```
const a =  {transactions: [
            {
                "amounts": 12.96,
                "balance": 0,
                "description": "",
                "occurred_at": "2017-09-23T19:18:21+00:00",
                "type": "refund"
            },
            {
                "amounts": 12.96,
                "balance": 0,
                "description": "",
                "occurred_at": "2017-09-23T19:18:21+00:00",
                "type": "adjustment"
            },
            {
                "amounts": 12.96,
                "balance": 0,
                "description": "",
                "occurred_at": "2017-09-23T19:18:21+00:00",
                "type": "purchase"
            },
  ]
};  

const filterByType = _.groupBy({...a.transactions}, 'type');
```

The `filterByType` will contain desired data as :

```
{
  "refund": [
    {
      "amounts": 12.96,
      "balance": 0,
      "description": "",
      "occurred_at": "2017-09-23T19:18:21+00:00",
      "type": "refund"
    }
  ],
  "adjustment": [
    {
      "amounts": 12.96,
      "balance": 0,
      "description": "",
      "occurred_at": "2017-09-23T19:18:21+00:00",
      "type": "adjustment"
    }
  ],
  "purchase": [
    {
      "amounts": 12.96,
      "balance": 0,
      "description": "",
      "occurred_at": "2017-09-23T19:18:21+00:00",
      "type": "purchase"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So i have to first store my API data in constant, right @ajay ?

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to store this somewhere

Comment: hey @Ajay, how to filter onClick, for example i have clicked purchase type and after clicking i have to show only purchase type ?

Comment: You must be storing your initial data somewhere, so you can also make run time calculations to get this data.

Comment: You can write the `groupBy` code in your `onClick`  method

Comment: i am storing my data in this constant const transaction = (data && data.transactions) ? data.transactions : [];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159618/discussion-between-ajay-gaur-and-wali).

Answer (score 2):

I make from this first use filter, how I can chose what is need of data and then use map method how can rendered list data.  Because in many case better is use Id field and then read this row of data.

```
  const pera=[
    {"id": 1,"title": "Prvi"},
    {"id": 2, "title": "Drugi"},
    {"id": 3, "title": "Treci"},
    {"id": 4, "title": "Cetvrti"},
    {"id": 5, "title": "Peti"},
    {"id": 6, "title": "Sesti"},
    {"id": 7, "title": "Sedmi"},
    {"id": 8, "title": "Osmi"},
    {"id": 9, "title": "Deveti"},
    {"id": 10, "title": "Desti"}
    ];


class Proba extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            mika:[],
        };
    }

    render(){

        const  mika = pera.filter(id=>{
            return (id.id=== 2);
        });
        const mika1 = mika.map((primer,i)=>{
            return(
              <div key={primer.id}>
                  {primer.id} {primer.title}
              </div>
            );
        });
```

On this away we ever get what is need with this sample key.But this idea you can use and for complex problem, because we must get soluction at start point how problem don't stay biggar